# php registration code not working properly

Tags: php, registration

The code below should give an error or ok above the form when click the submit button. But the problem is it wont do anything. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here?

```
<?php
include 'ini.php';
?>

<?php
if(isset ( $_POST['reg_u_name'],$_POST['reg_email'], $_POST['reg_password'] )) {
$reg_u_name = $_POST['reg_u_name'];
$reg_email = $_POST['reg_email'];
$reg_password = $_POST['reg_password'];

$errors = array();

if (empty($reg_u_name) || empty($reg_email) || empty($reg_password)) {
    $errors[] = 'All fields required';
}else{
    echo 'OK';
}

}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<p>Username:<br/><input type="text" name="reg_u_name" maxlength="20"  ></p>
<p>Email:<br/><input type="text" name="reg_email" maxlength="20" ></p>
<p>Password:<br/><input type="password" name="reg_password" maxlength="20" ></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Register"></p>
</form>
```

the ini.php file

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
require 'connect.php';
include 'user.func.php';
?>
```

Comment: The code is correct, can you show the code of `ini.php`

Comment: after submit ,print_r($errors),print_r($_POST) what u see

Comment: u have to add in form action this code $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Comment: @Kishore, Check my latest edit. it works. tested.

Comment: @MayurKukadiya No you don't.  A blank action defaults to submitting it itself.

Comment: Got it guys Thank you for the help. And jon special thanks to you. See the comments in jon's answer for what was going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just **one** value from your post array isn't set, then your if condition is never met, meaning that you won't get any of the display you are expecting.

I would suggest checking individually for setting your personal variables and doing the `if` on `$_POST['submit']`.  *Also*, you never doing anything with your `$errors` array if it does get assigned. ^^

The following works for me:

```
<?php

if(isset ( $_POST['reg_u_name'],$_POST['reg_email'], $_POST['reg_password'] )) {
$reg_u_name = $_POST['reg_u_name'];
$reg_email = $_POST['reg_email'];
$reg_password = $_POST['reg_password'];

$errors = array();

if (empty($reg_u_name) || empty($reg_email) || empty($reg_password)) {
    echo 'All fields required';
}else{
    echo 'OK';
}

}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<p>Username:<br/><input type="text" name="reg_u_name" maxlength="20"  ></p>
<p>Email:<br/><input type="text" name="reg_email" maxlength="20" ></p>
<p>Password:<br/><input type="password" name="reg_password" maxlength="20" ></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Register"></p>
</form>
```

[PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tvw-gej)

Comment: @KishoreKumar what version of PHP?  Because it doesn't on my test.

Comment: @KishoreKumar did you click the fiddle link? Because it should work, tested in 5.4.7 and 5.3 and 5.4.13

Comment: it displays all fields are required before i hit submit button

Comment: Did you refresh the page, which resubmits the form?  Because that is the only way it would do that - on form submit.

Comment: i refreshed the page several times but it shows before i hit submit

Comment: exactly, don't refresh.  Click the title bar and hit enter so you don't resubmit the data.

Comment: thank you my code itself worked i did refresh only. now when hit enter it worked.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  I am curious who downvoted my answer now though because it has worked since the beginning. ^^

Comment: i didn't and i can't do it

Comment: @KishoreKumar I know you didn't - that's why I said I was curious. ;)

Comment: one more problem is when i click register the contents in the form disappears. is there a way to keep the contents if it has errors.And why the $errors[]= 'All fields required'; wont work but echo works. I saw in a video $errors[] works for him but not for me. Is there a reason?

Answer (score 1):

Try Now. This works.

```
    <?php
//include 'ini.php';
if(isset($_POST['subBtn']))
{
if(isset($_POST['reg_u_name'] ,$_POST['reg_email'], $_POST['reg_password'] ))
 {
$reg_u_name = $_POST['reg_u_name'];
$reg_email = $_POST['reg_email'];
$reg_password = $_POST['reg_password'];

if (empty($reg_u_name) || empty($reg_email) || empty($reg_password)) {
    echo 'All fields required';
}else{
    echo 'OK';
 }
 }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<p>Username:<br/><input type="text" name="reg_u_name" maxlength="20"  ></p>
<p>Email:<br/><input type="text" name="reg_email" maxlength="20" ></p>
<p>Password:<br/><input type="password" name="reg_password" maxlength="20" ></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Register" name="subBtn"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: You don't need the errors array here and just a single if loop is enough.

Comment: You remove the condition that checks if any of the fields are empty.

Comment: this code displays error or ok always before hitting the submit button

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran to expand on my comment, those `$_POST` fields will be set even if they are empty - so it wouldn't be 'ok'

Comment: it works for once after i refresh the page it shows all fields are required before i hit submit

Answer (score 0):

give name atrribute to input submite type like

```
 <input type="submit" name="regist" value="Register">
```

and change to this code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['regist']))
{
  $reg_u_name = $_POST['reg_u_name'];
  $reg_email = $_POST['reg_email'];
  $reg_password = $_POST['reg_password'];

  $errors = array();

  if (empty($reg_u_name) || empty($reg_email) || empty($reg_password)) {
   $errors[] = 'All fields required';
  }else{
    echo 'OK';
  }
}
?>
```

it will echo 'OK' if all form is filled.